# How to cancel onclicklistener if value is still null

Tags: android

This seems straightforward, but I am unsure how to do it and can't see it despite my searches! (Maybe some else can find duplicate)

The if statement won't work as "titleString" isn't initialized when packing my intent. Any ideas?

```
final Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                log("Entered submitButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");



                if (mTitleText.getText() != null) {
                    String titleString = mTitleText.getText().toString(); 
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please choose Vegetable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                String fullDate = dateString + " " + timeString;

                Intent data = new Intent();
                VegItem.packageIntent(data, titleString, fullDate);

                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Scratch that! Fixed it.. for those looking for this in the future:

String titleString = mTitleText.getText().toString(); 
    String fullDate = dateString + " " + timeString;


    Intent data = new Intent();
//    VegItem.packageIntent(data, titleString, priority, status, fullDate);

    if (titleString.equals(null))
    {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Please choose Vegetable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
     VegItem.packageIntent(data, titleString, fullDate);
     setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
     finish();
    }

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable the click listener just call

```
submitButton.setOnClickListener(null);
```

If you want to exit the click listener without executing the remainder of the code in it, just call

```
return;
```

Comment: RETURN! That completely slipped my mind.. thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I think `mTitleText.getText() != null` would not return `null` and you should use `mTitleText.getText().toString() != null` instead!

'getText()` will return an empty string if the editText is empty.